# Python script runs in pycharm but not in ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, linux

So I have a script that runs perfectly in PyCharm but errors out in the Ubuntu terminal:

Python Code

```py
# import dependencies #
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import os
import shutil

# make folder with today's date #
# if a folder with today's date already exists, a pass will be returned and the script will end #
today = datetime.now()
dst = "/home/name/Dropbox/Documents/Python/Projects/MiningCompanyAnalysis/Company_Listings/" + today.strftime(
    '%Y%m%d')
if os.path.exists(dst):
    pass
else:
    os.mkdir(dst)

    # download company listings from the internet #
    url_list = ['https://www.tsx.com/resource/en/101',
                'https://asx.api.markitdigital.com/asx-research/1.0/companies/directory/file?access_token'
                '=83ff96335c2d45a094df02a206a39ff4']

    r_tsx = requests.get(url_list[0], allow_redirects=True)
    r_asx = requests.get(url_list[1], allow_redirects=True)

    open('tsx_listings.xlsx', 'wb').write(r_tsx.content)
    open('asx_listings.csv', 'wb').write(r_asx.content)

    # move listing files to daily folder #
    src_tsx = "/home/name/Dropbox/Documents/Python/Projects/MiningCompanyAnalysis/Scripts/tsx_listings.xlsx"
    src_asx = "/home/name/Dropbox/Documents/Python/Projects/MiningCompanyAnalysis/Scripts/asx_listings.csv"
    src_list = [src_tsx, src_asx]

    for item in src_list:
        shutil.move(src_list[src_list.index(item)], dst)
```

Terminal Error

```
name@name-XPS-13-9310:~$ python3 '/home/name/Dropbox/Documents/Python/Projects/MiningCompanyAnalysis/Scripts/ubuntu_testing.py' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 788, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/name/Dropbox/Documents/Python/Projects/MiningCompanyAnalysis/Scripts/tsx_listings.xlsx' -> '/home/name/Dropbox/Documents/Python/Projects/MiningCompanyAnalysis/Company_Listings/20210704/tsx_listings.xlsx'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/name/Dropbox/Documents/Python/Projects/MiningCompanyAnalysis/Scripts/ubuntu_testing.py", line 34, in <module>
    shutil.move(src_list[src_list.index(item)], dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 802, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 432, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/name/Dropbox/Documents/Python/Projects/MiningCompanyAnalysis/Scripts/tsx_listings.xlsx'
```

The missing files/directories do not exist prior to the script being run, but they are created by the script. I am running the script from the same location that it is being run by PyCharm; I have also tried running the script using the PyCharm virtual environment from the terminal and it gives the same error.

Basically I don't understand why it will run fine in PyCharm and not in the Ubuntu terminal.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code? Or, if not possible, break it down to a minimal example?

Comment: Done it has been added.

Comment: Cannot post an answer, so I'll post a comment.
You open the src files with a relative path (first possible source of error), after writing to them you don't close them (second possible source of error). You need to close the files before they appear as files in the OS (before you can shutil.move them).
When writing files, it is better to use `open` as [context manager](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/)

Answer (score 1):

You should provide absolute paths when you are running it in terminal

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue because all of the paths start with /home which is absolute; is it not?

Comment: @jmcdivitt: All the paths in the error message start with /home, but we have no idea what's in your code because you didn't put any in your question.

Comment: I have now included the python code. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

So as Pedru alluded to the error was the result of writing the files using default paths and the open function:

```
open('tsx_listings.xlsx', 'wb').write(r_tsx.content)
open('asx_listings.csv', 'wb').write(r_asx.content)
```

The default relative paths selected by Pycharm and the Ubuntu terminal are different. I've corrected this by using the absolute paths in the script:

```
    # import dependencies #
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import os

# make folder with today's date #
# if a folder with today's date already exists, a pass will be returned and the script will end #
today = datetime.now()
dst = "/home/name/Dropbox/Documents/Python/Projects/MiningCompanyAnalysis/Company_Listings/" + today.strftime(
            '%Y%m%d')
if os.path.exists(dst):
    pass
else:
    os.mkdir(dst)

    # download company listings from the internet #
    url_list = ['https://www.tsx.com/resource/en/101',
                'https://asx.api.markitdigital.com/asx-research/1.0/companies/directory/file?access_token'
                '=83ff96335c2d45a094df02a206a39ff4']

    r_tsx = requests.get(url_list[0], allow_redirects=True)
    r_asx = requests.get(url_list[1], allow_redirects=True)

    open(f'{dst}/tsx_listings.xlsx', 'wb').write(r_tsx.content)
    open(f'{dst}/asx_listings.csv', 'wb').write(r_asx.content)
```

This code now runs in both Pycharm and the Ubuntu terminal. The solution code has also been simplified as by saving the files directly to their desired destination folder, it is no longer necessary to move the files by using shutil.

Thanks to Pedru and Hridaya for the input.